# Android AccountPicker 'Add account' doesen't refresh the options

Tags: android, account, accountmanager, accountpicker

When my app starts, I'd like to ask my users either to create an `Account` or to choose from existing ones. I've implemented an `Authenticator` (extended `AccountAuthenticatorActivity`, `AbstractAccountAuthenticator`, made a `Service`) It seems to be working, I can create new Accounts from Settings/Accounts.

When I start an `AccountPicker`, I get a list of already created Accounts. When I click `Add acccount` it shows up my `Account` creation `Activity`. But when I'm done with account creation, finishing that Activity, and going back to the `AccountPicker` I dont see a new option of the newly created `Account`. Although if I restart the app, the recently created `Account` is in the list.

How I start the `AccountPicker`:

```
Intent intent = accountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, new String[]{"test_namespace"}, null, null, null, null);
startActivityForResult(intent, TEST_CODE);
```

My questions:

- Is it supposed to work like this?
- Can I reload the content of the `AccountPicker` after I created a new
  `Account`?
- Can I just simply return an `Intent` with the newly created `Account` when I
  return from my `Account` creation `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

In my authenticator activity, after the user authenticates on the server I check the existing accounts and explicitly add the account if it's not there:

```
    boolean accountRegistered = false;
    Account account = new Account(username, AccountAuthenticator.ACCOUNT_TYPE_MYAPP);
    AccountManager acctMgr = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = acctMgr.getAccountsByType(AccountAuthenticator.ACCOUNT_TYPE_MYAPP);
    for (Account acct : accounts) {
        if (acct.equals(account)) {
            accountRegistered = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (accountRegistered) {
        acctMgr.setPassword(account, password);
    } else {
        acctMgr.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);
    }
```

After I do this, I see the account in the account picker.

I can't guarantee this is 100% correct; with the undocumented authentication classes, we're all flying blind.